# I expect a float but get a numpy array

Tags: python, numeric, differential-equations

I’m writing a program for my physics class that puts out a numerical solution of an differential equation using the runge kutta method. I already made on for the harmonic oszilator that works just fine. However trying to implement it to this new problem I get a problem where I expect a certain value to be a float (which works just fine in my other Programm) but I get a nparry. Could somebody pls help me? I cantaloupe  figure out where my mistake is.

Here is my the problematic part of my problem

```
def runge_kutta_ode(x, param_vec, init_vec):
    N = x.size
    delta = x[1]-x[0]
    g = np.zeros(N, dtype = complex)
    f = np.zeros(N, dtype = complex)
    h = np.zeros(N, dtype = complex)
    f[0] = init_vec[0]
    g[0] = init_vec[1]
    h[0] = init_vec[2]
    for i in range(1,N):
        f_old = g[i-1]
        g_old = f[i-1]
        h_old = h[i-1]
        
        [k1_f, k1_g, k1_h] = get_derivative(f_old, g_old, h_old, param_vec)
        [k2_f, k2_g, k2_h] = get_derivative(f_old+delta*k1_f/2.0, g_old+delta*k1_g/2.0, h_old+delta*k1_h/2.0, param_vec)
        [k3_f, k3_g, k3_h] = get_derivative(f_old+delta*k2_f/2.0, g_old+delta*k2_g/2.0, h_old+delta*k2_h/2.0, param_vec)
        [k4_f, k4_g, k4_h] = get_derivative(f_old+delta*k3_f, g_old+delta*k3_g, h_old+delta*k3_h, param_vec)

        g[i] = f_old + delta/6.0 * (k1_f+2.0*k2_f+2.0*k3_f+k4_f)
        g[i] = g_old + delta/6.0 * (k1_g+2.0*k2_g+2.0*k3_g+k4_g)
        h[i] = h_old + delta/6.0 * (k1_h+2.0*k2_h+2.0*k3_f+k4_h)
    return f, g, h
```

The k‘s is where the problem lies but as I mentioned in my other Programm I get no such problem.

Excuse me if my question is not structured properly this is my first questioned I post here

---

Get derivative is a function which saves my differantial equations.

```
def get_derivative(f, g, h, param_vec): 
    h_bar_i = 0.66j 
    phi = param_vec[0] 
    T_1 = param_vec[1] 
    T_2 = param_vec[2] 
    tau = param_vec[3] 
    dE_0 = param_vec[4] 
    f_dot = ((phi-h_bar_i/T_2)*f+(g-h)*1/2*dE_0*np.exp(-(x/(0.6*tau))**2))/h_bar_i 
    g_dot = ((-1/2*dE_0*np.exp(-(x/(0.6*tau))**2))*(-f+f.conjugate())-h_bar_ig/T_1)/h_bar_i 
    h_dot = ((-1/2*dE_0*np.exp(-(x/(0.6*tau))**2))*(f-f.conjugate())-h_bar_ih/T_1)/h_bar_i 
    return f_dot, g_dot, h_dot
```

Comment: What does `get_derivative` look like?

Comment: Try printing what k looks like. If it's an np.array of just one element then you just select that element.

Comment: Get derivative is a function which saves my differantial equations. 
def get_derivative(f, g, h, param_vec):
 h_bar_i = 0.66j
 phi = param_vec[0]
 T_1 = param_vec[1]
 T_2 = param_vec[2]
 tau = param_vec[3]
 dE_0 = param_vec[4]
 f_dot = ((phi-h_bar_i/T_2)*f+(g-h)*1/2*dE_0*np.exp(-(x/(0.6*tau))**2))/h_bar_i
 g_dot = ((-1/2*dE_0*np.exp(-(x/(0.6*tau))**2))*(-f+f.conjugate())-h_bar_i*g/T_1)/h_bar_i
 h_dot = ((-1/2*dE_0*np.exp(-(x/(0.6*tau))**2))*(f-f.conjugate())-h_bar_i*h/T_1)/h_bar_i
 return f_dot, g_dot, h_dot

Comment: Please [edit] the question if you want to add or change information. Comments are not suitable for anything but the most trivial code.

Comment: If i try to just pick a element I still don’t get the right result. The graph I plot is a constant but it should be declining

Comment: Oh okay Mister miyagi i didn’t know that

Comment: Please add the exact error message or the exact difference between the result you got and the result you expected. Largely the code looks correct, but you should next think about changing from the component-wise application of the RK4 steps to the vectorized version, using numpy arrays as state vectors.